# How to surpass Swift 4's Var naming restrictions?

Tags: ios, json, swift, syntax-error, swift4

I have a JSON data pulled from API and one of the key is `"24h_volume"`.

When I try to put `24h_volume` as a *constant* inside my `Decodable struct` giving me error:

> Expected a digit after integer literal prefix.

From what I understand, Swift syntax does not allow variables names starting with numbers.

What is the simplest way to surpass this restriction and successfully pull the data from the source?

Comment: What is the problem? The Swift properties need not have the same name as the JSON dictionary keys.

Comment: When I decode the JSON in Swift 4 it assigns all the values to their relative names in the Class. So when I give exact names to the constants in the class, I get their values from downloaded data.

Comment: You did not tell that you are using Swift 4 or JSONDecoder ...

Comment: I am sorry, I fixed it on the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear from your question but, if you are using Swift 4 JSON decoding support, you can define a custom `CodingKeys` enumeration for that. For instance:

```
struct Data: Decodable {
    var volume24: String
    var xxx: String
    ...

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case volume24 = “24h_volume”
        case xxx
        case ...
    }
}
```

You must then define a `case` for each property in your `struct` otherwise it will be ignored by `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: This is what I am looking for, however my struct is Decodable?

Comment: @sc13 No problem, it works the same ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @sc13 Nice, glad to help ;)